# Storage Quota Exceeded Error during AWS Glue Data Preview Execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I need help for an error occurred while attempting to run a data preview in AWS Glue Visual ETL. The error message suggests that there is a problem with the execution of the data preview job.

Error details:

```
{
  "error": {
    "stack": "Error: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': Setting the value of 'gs-datapreview-tspfV2TpH3UsL9TMXraaiXPAchYemtz1' exceeded the quota.\n at Object.setItem (https://a.b.cdn.console.awsstatic.com/a/v1/LKHF6KFR56O3XLCBNWJVPDBUVG7QB4QGVJRHKD7JFDXCGZJRNHBA/vendors.js:2:845813)\n  at p (https://a.b.cdn.console.awsstatic.com/a/v1/LKHF6KFR56O3XLCBNWJVPDBUVG7QB4QGVJRHKD7JFDXCGZJRNHBA/vendors.js:2:848532)\n  at ... (truncated)",
    "info": {
      "componentStack": "... (truncated)"
    }
  }
}
```

The error indicates a problem with the 'setItem' operation on 'Storage', specifically exceeding the quota for a certain value. This issue is impacting the successful execution of the data preview.

Glue Job Type: Spark
ETL Language: Python 3
Glue Version: Glue 4.0 - Supports spark 3.3, Scala 2, Python 3

I need to know if there's documentation for this occurred issue?

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue with the help of AWS Support. The error was due to exceeding the storage quota limit during a data preview job in Visual ETL. The recommended solution is to adjust the data preview preferences by reducing the row count setting from the default 200 rows to 50 or less. This optimization helps efficiently handle large datasets.

To implement the solution:

Click on the settings icon (gear symbol) to access preview preferences.
Under Preferences, update the "Number of Rows" field from 200 (default) to 50.
This adjustment should resolve the storage quota issue.